# Half overlay effect on CardView

Tags: android, css, xml, android-cardview

I'm trying to replicate this half, semi-transparent overlay effect (obtained with css) in Android Studio using xml. However, I've got troubles in figuring out how to do that. Some indications would be very appreciated!

The Background is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:startColor="#ff4800"
                android:endColor="#ffee01"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I think I should apply another xml file as Foreground, but I don't know how to code it to create that effect.

[image]

Comment: Share what you got so far so we can help. We can't build you the thing from scratch

Comment: Just added the xml file for the background.